# Position buttons with wx.BoxSizer

Tags: python, wxpython

I test wx.BoxSizer with wxPython 3.0.2.0 release.

That's what I like to do:

I would create a frame including a panel with 4 buttons.

I would like the first button is positioned on the top left, the second, top right, the third at the bottom left and the fourth bottom right of the screen.

I submit to you my code below.

Could you tell me if it is correct?

Thank you in advance.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent = None, title="Test of BoxSizer")
        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        hbox=wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        hbox1=wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.panel=wx.Panel(self)
        self.btn1=wx.Button(self.panel, label="Button 1")
        self.btn2=wx.Button(self.panel, label="Button 2")
        self.btn3=wx.Button(self.panel, label="Button 3")
        self.btn4=wx.Button(self.panel, label="Button 4")
        hbox.Add(self.btn1, proportion = 1, flag=wx.CENTER | wx.ALL, border=5)
        hbox.Add((0,0), proportion=4, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        hbox.Add(self.btn2, proportion = 1, flag=wx.CENTER | wx.ALL, border=5)
        hbox1.Add(self.btn3, proportion = 1, flag=wx.CENTER | wx.ALL, border=5)
        hbox1.Add((0,0), proportion=4, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        hbox1.Add(self.btn4, proportion = 1, flag=wx.CENTER | wx.ALL, border=5)
        vbox.Add(hbox, proportion = 1, flag=wx.CENTER | wx.ALL, border = 5)
        #vbox.Add((0,0), proportion = 1, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        vbox.Add(hbox1, proportion = 1, flag=wx.CENTER | wx.ALL, border = 5)
        self.panel.SetSizer(vbox)
        vbox.SetSizeHints(self)
        self.Centre()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(redirect = False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    frame.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution to my problem of positioning buttons in a panel.

I simply used the proportion parameter of the Add method of the sizer wx.BoxSizer.

I submit my corrected code below, hoping that this will help other newbies like me.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent = None, title="Test of BoxSizer")
        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        hbox=wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        hbox1=wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.panel=wx.Panel(self)
        self.btn1=wx.Button(self.panel, label="button 1")
        self.btn2=wx.Button(self.panel, label="button 2")
        self.btn3=wx.Button(self.panel, label="button 3")
        self.btn4=wx.Button(self.panel, label="button 4")
        hbox.Add(self.btn1, proportion = 1, flag=wx.CENTER | wx.ALL, border=5)
        hbox.Add((0,0), proportion=4, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        hbox.Add(self.btn2, proportion = 1, flag=wx.CENTER | wx.ALL, border=5)
        hbox1.Add(self.btn3, proportion = 1, flag=wx.CENTER | wx.ALL, border=5)
        hbox1.Add((0,0), proportion=4, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        hbox1.Add(self.btn4, proportion = 1, flag=wx.CENTER | wx.ALL, border=5)
        vbox.Add(hbox, proportion = 1, flag=wx.CENTER | wx.ALL, border = 5)
        #vbox.Add((0,0), proportion = 4, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        vbox.Add(hbox1, proportion = 1, flag=wx.CENTER | wx.ALL, border = 5)
        self.panel.SetSizer(vbox)
        vbox.SetSizeHints(self)
        self.Centre()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(redirect = False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    frame.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: You can do it this way or you can call `AddStretchSpacer` from your sizer. Another approach would be to use a GridSizer.